# Laravel, migrations Schema class

Tags: laravel, database-migration

Hy, i have question about creating table(generally working with DB) in laravel through migrations.

I have something like this(from code happy)

```
    <?php
        Schema::create('users', function($table) {

        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('username', 32);
        $table->string('email', 320);
        $table->string('password', 64);

        $table->integer('role');

        $table->boolean('active');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

OK this will create table "users" with 9 fields, but I'm getting confused by this callback. First of all variable "$table" is instance of which class? Can someone explain me what happened here, respectively how this works?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, here's how it happens:

1. When you call `Schema::create()`, it creates a `Blueprint` object, linked to the table's name you passed as argument.
2. The second parameter, the callback, is a `Closure` that will receive this previously created `Blueprint` object as the `$table` argument, and act on it.
3. When you call methods on the `$table` object, it is actually wiring it to a `Grammar` class, according to your database. That is, if you are using a MySQL database, it will use `MySqlGrammar` class. This ensures you get valid SQL for any database you use, without having to worry about it.
4. Finally, it executes all the commands, and does all the job for you.

If you wish to see the actual SQL queries generated, you can add the `--pretend` option to the `migrate` command. I'd recommend saving it in a file, so you can read it more easily. Ex:

```
php artisan migrate --pretend > app/storage/migration.sql
```

This would save it in `app/storage/migration.sql` file.